# Variation of 'Secretary Problem'

Tags: probability

First time poster - just learning the ropes around here.

I have a question about the famous "Secretary Problem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem).

The "Secretary Problem" is about a situation on how to :

- Optimally select the best candidate for a job '
- Without having to interview every candidate
- And being unable to select a candidate that was interviewed in the past
- After interviewing how many candidates should we stop the interview process?

As an example, suppose there are 100 candidates for a job. We assume that these candidates have a different skill level (e.g. Candidate 100 = best, Candidate 1 = worst) and we are looking for the candidate with the highest skill level.

- We also assume that these candidates are randomly ordered as well as independent from one another - that means we interview the 2nd best candidate from the list of 100, the next candidate on the list could be the 81st candidate.
- We assume we do not know the skill of each candidate (i.e. true ranking) until the interview is over
- We also assume that we interviewed 5 candidates in the following order - Candidate 14, Candidate 4, Candidate 74, Candidate 19, Candidate 98. Suppose after we interviewed Candidate 98, we realize that Candidate 4 was the best - and now we want to offer Candidate 4 a job.
- Unfortunately in this math problem, we are unable to offer Candidate 4 a job since we have already rejected this candidate.

This is a fundamental requirement of the Secretary Problem - when rejecting a potential candidate, we do so while taking the risk that its possible we are rejecting the best possible candidate

Now, if we break this problem down into solely a mathematical problem - i.e., suppose there are 100 random numbers (e.g. we know that there are 100 numbers, but we don't know the range of these numbers - e.g. 100 random numbers between 1 - 1000 or 1 - 5000) : suppose we see "n" of these random numbers - what value of "n" should we select to maximize the probability of encountering the highest number on this list?

Using math, a solution has been derived - regardless of how many candidates are there:

- If there are a total of "n" candidates, interview the first "n/e" candidates (where "e" is Euler's Number)
- Then, choose the candidate that performed better than all these "n/e" candidates
- This will result in the overall best candidate being selected roughly 37% of the time time.

Now - my question: This solution (stop after n/e candidates and then select best candidate) to the Secretary Problem relies on the key assumption that the distribution of candidates is random -  but what if the distribution of candidates is "semi-random"? That is, what if given a "random number":

- There is a 0.5 probability that the next number will be another random number
- There is a 0.5 probability that the next number will be the previous number + 1

Below is some Python code to run this simulation:

```
import time

def sample(lst, k):
    # Seed the random number generator with the current time
    random.seed(time.time())

    # Generate k random indices
    indices = random.sample(range(len(lst)), k)

    # Return the elements at those indices
    return [lst[i] for i in indices]

i = sample(range(1, 101), 1)[0]
j = [i]

for x in range(99):
    if (i + 1) in j:
        i = sample(list(set(range(1, 101)) - set(j)), 1)[0]
    else:
        if random.random() > 0.5 or i == 100:
            i = sample(list(set(range(1, 101)) - set(j)), 1)[0]
        else:
            i = i + 1
    j.append(i)
```

And the resulting data looks something like this:

```
  55  26  79  28  58  35  36  27  97  98  99  56  57  13  14  90  91   4  87  88  75  76  77  78  69
   39  40  41  42  44  45  46  47  48  54  34  24  80  60  61  62  63  86  59  38  70  71  72  22  12
    2   3  10  11  66  49  96  23   9  94  95  29  30  31  89   6  65  32  52  53   7   8 100  92  93
  51  81  82  50  17  18   5  67  83  84  85  37  16  74  73  68  25  33   1  20  43  15  19  21  31
```

Thus, given this modification to the classic Secretary Problem - can we also modify the solution to the existing Secretary Problem and come across some new solution? Or does this modification completely "break" the problem and the optimal strategy now is random guessing?

Thanks!

Comment: it would be interesting to learn about further variations - e.g.

Comment: 1) secretary problem with replacement (i.e. same candidate can appear more than once)

Comment: 2) "m" total candidates but you can only see "n" where m>n

Comment: The original problem assumes that all we know about candidate is how they rank compared to previous - we don't have numerical estimation of this rank. So, the $+1$ in your variant doesn't fit it. Do you assume that we now know numerical estimation of candidate quality, or does your $+1$ means "next candidate is better than previous one, but it's all we know"?

Comment: If you know the distribution of the "random number" then I think you can solve this variant.